# Using Fundamental theorem of calculus with another variable inside the integral

Tags: calculus

So, I have this problem:
$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{3x+1}} x^2f(t) dt = \frac{2}{ax} + ax$, and I need to find $f(t)$.

I know I should derivate at both sides so I can use the fundamental theorem of calculus.
The thing is, can I take that $x^2$ out of the integral? I tried doing so, but then when I tried to derivate, I found I needed to use the product rule, which then made the whole thing worse.

If I don't need to take the $x^2$ out, what should I do?

I know that if it wasn't there, I could simply do $\frac{d}{dx}(\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{3x+1}} f(t) dt) = f(\frac{1}{3x+1}) \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{3x+1})$  and then I can just go from there, but I don't know what to do with the $x^2$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can naturally take out the x^2 out of the integral, since in relation to t it's a constant.

Comment: @JoãoVíctorMelo Thanks, I was really wondering if that was right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$\int_0^\frac{1}{3x+1}x^2f(t)dt=x^2\int _0^\frac{1}{3x+1}f(t)dt$$

$$=ax+\frac{2}{ax}$$

$$\implies \int_0^\frac{1}{3x+1}f(t)dt=\frac ax+\frac{2}{ax^3}$$

the differentiation gives

$$f(\frac{1}{3x+1})\frac{-3}{(3x+1)^2}=-\frac{a}{x^2}-\frac{6}{ax^4}$$

to get $ f(X=\frac{1}{3x+1}) $, replace $ x $ by

$$\frac 13(\frac 1X-1)$$

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I didn't think of taking the $x^2$ out before derivating.